# postMessage to webView in useEffect in React Native is executed earlier than adding message event listener

Tags: reactjs, react-native, next.js, webview

In React Native, I'm calling `postMessage` to webView in `useEffect`. I wanna do this after my webView mounts.
But It seems `postMessage` is executed earlier than `addEventListener` to message event in webView, so the webView doesn't listen to the message event at the time.

I tried putting `isWebViewLoaded` value in deps of `useEffect` like below but it doesn't work.
`isWebViewLoaded` becomes `true` when prop function `onLoadEnd` to Webview is executed.

```js
  useEffect(() => {
    if (!isWebViewLoaded) return;
    // postMessage code
  }, [isWebViewLoaded]);
```

How can I deal with this?